# How to mix categorical data with compressed Sparse row matrix in a pandas data frame in classification problem

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix, categorical-data

I'm constructing a pandas data-frame as an input for some sklearn machine learning models. It is a supervised learning problem that consists in classify 'words' to different labels. I got categorical, numerical and text data. The text data is already tokenised. So in feature 'text' I have single words. Meaning that, there is one word per row.

I already encode every-feature but the words. I have thought about using sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer for one-hot-encode the words. However, I got 316511 instances/words and 161880 unique labels so I created a total of 161920 features. This increased the weight of the pandas data-frame up to 47GB. This is not feasible for my laptop/cloud instance so I had to find another way to handle this large dataset. I found that HashingVectorizer as another way to encode large dataset in a more optimised way https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html

I used this:

```
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(decode_error='ignore', n_features=1000,
                               alternate_sign=True)

df_reduced['text'] = vectorizer.transform(df_reduced['text']).astype(np.float16)
```

and the result is:

> <316511x1000 sparse matrix of type ''
>       with 380055 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Thanks to this the final dataframe weights only 22MB. However when apply some of the sklearn models there is an internal error that must be related with the structure of the data as I have OHE features + numerical features (scaled) and this CSR matrix format:

```
~/PycharmProjects/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So, how can I use pandas data - frame with this kind of data?

This is an example of an instance of the data-frame:

```
label    num_feature_1      num_feature_2     num_feature_3     num_feature_4  \
0  Sold-to-party Name  0.897949  0.989258  0.39209  0.070618   

                                                text    length  \
0    (0, 84)\t1.0\n  (1, 84)\t1.0\n  (2, 8)\t-1.0...  0.654785  0.119995   

   start_with_capital  is_Inner_Cap         ...          is_upper  is_lower  \
0                   1             0         ...                 0         0
```

and this is an example of some of the features, with the text feature which in fact is the CSR_matrix gotten from HashingVectorizer.

```
label                               316511 non-null object
num_feature_1                       316511 non-null float16
num_feature_2                       316511 non-null float16
num_feature_3                       316511 non-null float16
num_feature_4                       316511 non-null float16
text                                316511 non-null object
length                              316511 non-null float16
start_with_capital                  316511 non-null uint8
is_upper                            316511 non-null uint8
ending_with_colon                   316511 non-null uint8
```

****EDIT
I already tried to transform the outcome of HashingVectorizer to array and I found the following unique values and its counts

```
df_reduced['text'] = vectorizer.transform(df_reduced['text']).toarray().astype(np.float16)

df_reduced['text'].value_counts()



 0.000000    316246
 1.000000       130
-1.000000        61
 0.707031        21
-0.500000        16
-0.707031        16
-0.447266         7
-0.577148         7
-0.408203         3
-0.377930         2
 0.447266         1
-0.333252         1
```

I am not sure if this makes sense as most of the instances are encoded as 0.

Comment: did you tried converting to array using .toarray() or use .todense() and then create a dataframe of this and give it to the input of sklearn models?

Comment: @Vishal yes, I have tried that... but does it really make sense to do that? I got the following value_counts0.000000    316246
 1.000000       130
-1.000000        61
 0.707031        21
-0.500000        16
-0.707031        16
-0.447266         7
-0.577148         7
-0.408203         3
-0.377930         2
 0.447266         1
-0.333252         1

Comment: with some models, you can use the output of vectorizer directly, with others you can use the output after doing .toarray() or .todense(). The number of 0's are very high. you can do some text cleaning before doing vectorizing.

Comment: what do you mean by "text cleaning". almost all my words are unique (60-70% of the total) @Vishal

Comment: like stemming, spell correction, lowercase, removing stop words etc

Comment: no, I got already the words tokenised (single words). @Vishal

Comment: After tokenizing, you can do stemming, lowercase, stopwords removal, etc on each word.